# Android: RecyclerView Adapter stopping at constructor

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView's adapter is not working, I have **added logs everywhere** to see the event activity but it is not moving forward from the constructor of the class; tried multiple approaches but was not able to find the solution for the same. Below is the code.

**EDIT: I have added the setData method as per the first answer but it shows an error:**

`Cannot resolve method 'setData(List<String)'`

**HomeFragment.java**

```
final List<String> mQuestion = new ArrayList<>();
        homeViewModel.getmQuestionsData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> mQuestionsList) {
                mQuestion.addAll(mQuestionsList);
            }
        });

        adapter = new mAdapter(getContext(), mQuestion);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**mAdapter.java**

```
class mAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<mAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String TAG = "Adapter";

    public mAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        Log.d(TAG,"Constructor");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public mAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        Log.d(TAG,"CreateView");
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull mAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,"BindView");
        String question = mData.get(position);
        holder.question.setText(question);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public void setData(List<String> questions) {

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView question;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d(TAG,"ViewHolder");
            question = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you init Adapter? I mean what lifecyle callback in fragment you put your code?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand what you were trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the list you are passing is empty.

Change your constructor to this, and post the logcat output:

```
public mAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
    Log.d(TAG,"Constructor");
    for (String s : mData)
    {
       Log.d(TAG, "In mAdapter: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's all it shows, then the list mQuestion you are passing to the adapter constructor is empty - the list has no items, that's why your recylerview wont show anything.

Comment: okay so the recyclerview and the adpater are correct right? I will try the same with a demo list. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add `void setData(List<String> data)` method to your adapter and update `mData` from this method, not from constructor like this:

```
public void setData(List<String> data) {
    mData = data;
}
```

After that call this method from `onChanged` callback like this:

```
adapter = new mAdapter(getContext());
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
homeViewModel.getmQuestionsData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new 
    Observer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<String> mQuestionsList) {
            adapter.setData(mQuestionsList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This code shows the following error:

Cannot resolve method 'setData(List<String)'

Comment: that's because you need to create a fuction named `setData(data)` that assign `data` to your `mData`

Comment: I've written for you setData method, put it in your mAdapter class @ShlokJain